# Laravel CRUD: how to update input field to null?

Tags: forms, laravel, input, laravel-5.6

This is the input field from CRUD 'edit' page. On page load it is populated with some value from database.

```
<input type="text" name="lives" value="{{ old('lives', $card->lives) }}">
```

When I clear this input field (delete old or retrieved string) and submit form, there still is old data in `$request->('lives')`!

I already have one solution: if I delete old value from input field and enter a single space – it works, and `$request->('lives')` contains `null` (thanks to `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middlewares).

But I want it to work properly when I just empty input field and submit form.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

P.S. There is no problem with `<textarea>` fields, because they don't have attribute 'value', and old data is pasted between tags.

```
<textarea>{{ old('data', $card->data) }}</textarea>
```

Comment: Can you dump your request that the server receives when you submit something with the "lives" cleared?

Comment: What does the update method look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a condition to your controller action method

```
$data = $request->all();

$data['lives'] = 
    (isset($data['lives']) && !empty($data['lives'])) ? $data['lives'] : NULL;
```

Comment: Shorter (and more elegant) version for this is would be: `$data['lives'] = $request->filled('lives') ? $request->get('lives') : null;`, but the solution shouldn't be do have to do that for every input manually - there must be something wrong elsewhere.